# Междометия и междометные единицы

Tags: грамматика, междометие, морфология

В чем принципиальное отличие между междометиями и междометными единицами?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря о чём речь. Как слово - единица лексики, так и междометие - одна из междометных единиц. Т.е. междометная единица - широкое понятие, междометие - узкое.

**Междометные  единицы - все слова и выражения, функционирующие в роли междометий**:

собственно первообразные междометия (*А! Ну! Эх!*);

другие части речи в роли междометий (производные междометия - *Глупости! Беда! Крышка!*);

междометные фразеологизмы (*Боже мой! Вот так история!*)

кто-то включает сюда и звукоподражания, и слова вежливости, кто-то нет.

Некоторые учёные различают **междометие как слово и междометную единицу как высказывание, фразеологический оборот**.

Междометие-слово: *Ай! Ах! Ага! Увы!*, междометная единица - фразеологическое сочетание: *А как же! Вот это да!*

Что Вы имеете в виду - не знаю. Что Вы понимаете под МЕ?